# T4MVC: What are MVC.Controller.ActionParams are for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

I've found properties corresponding to each action named like this: `MVC.<Controller>.<Action>Params`, they contain parameter names for each action. What are they for and how they can be used?

Comment: oh right my answer is out of scope...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some edge scenarios where it was interesting to pass the parameter name as a constant. I can't instantly recall what that person was doing, but I could see this being useful is calls to AddRouteValue. In the end, it's all about never to have to use a literal string that refers to a C# object, whether it's a class, method, or param.

Comment: David, I was waiting for you to answer :) Just in time :)